# Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:587. R

Tags: r, email, outlook

I am attempting to send an email from R using Outlook using the send.mail function

I have done the following and get this error 'EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:587'

Here is my script and also how would I create an attachment to it

```
install.packages('mailR')
library(mailR)
library(rJava)
send.mail(from = "myemail",
          to = c("audience email"),
          subject = "Test",
          body = "Hello from R.",
          authenticate = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.office365.com",
                      port = 587,
                      user.name = "my email",
                      passwd = 'my password',
                      tls = TRUE))
```

I am also fine with a potential alternative, quite simply what I want to do is send an email to group of people from my work email with an attached CSV

Comment: Make sure your `from=` is exactly as O365 thinks; it does not allow sending on behalf of a different account name (such as from a service account). As an example, I have a "service email address" (`tech@...`) that is forwarded to my real address. I used to be able to send `From: tech@mycompany.com`, but some time recently they instituted tighter security measures. Now all email sent from my "service account" must truly come from my address, not `tech@`.

Comment: yes, it is my exact email from the company I work for. Not a different email.

Comment: What is the exact error as returned by the SMTP server?